# synchronised audio streaming

Tags: audio, audio-playback, chromecast

What are the options to use 2 or more raspberry (any version) for multi-room synchronised audio streaming? 
Something like [Google Chromecast Audio](https://www.google.com/chromecast/audio/)

I don't mean a full ready solution, any starting point will do :)

Answer (score 1):

I just found an option that does just that with the pi:

https://github.com/badaix/snapcast

PS: marking this community, feel free to add other possibilities